# Vue3 Syncfusion ej2 dropdowns Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Below is the error in the console
`vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:3302 TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined     at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)     at extendStatics (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-base/src/component-base.js:19:16)     at __extends (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-base/src/component-base.js:22:9)     at oval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-base/src/component-base.js:59:5)     at oval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-base/src/component-base.js:481:2)     at Module../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-base/src/component-base.js (5.js:1883:1)     at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854:30)     at fn (app.js:151:20)     at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-base/src/index.js:2:73)     at Module../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-base/src/index.js (5.js:1907:1)`
what are the possible solutions to the error

All possible solutions to the such errors in the console as far as Vue3 and syncfusion are concerned.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ya I solved by changing the version of vue/cli